# Consuming .Net DLL from Classic ASP page results in "invalid pointer" error

Tags: .net, com, asp-classic

I created a simple test class and went through the steps to make it COM-visible. I can create the object from an ASP page just fine. When I go through the EXACT same steps with the real class I get a "Server.CreateObject Failed ~ INVALID POINTER" error. I can't find anything on the Web specifically about the INVALID POINTER error.

Here are the steps I went through to make it COM-Visible.

1. Run "tlbexp MyLibrary.dll /out:MyLibrary.tlb"

2. Register it : regasm /tlb:MyLibrary.tlb MyLibrary.dll

3. GAC it : gacutil /i  MyLibrary.dll

4. Restart IIS.

Each of these steps is successful, but when I try to create the object I get the error. Anybody have any ideas?

**I found the answer. The DLL was named the same as the class. I took a stab in the dark and found that changing either the class name or the DLL name fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The DLL was named the same as the class. I took a stab in the dark and found that changing either the class name or the DLL name fixed the issue.